# build coreclr app on windows for different platform

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, coreclr

Can I define coreclr (asp.net core) target runtime for portable app that differ from development platform? Say build app under windows for Ubuntu? Thought that projects are platform independent so that only .net runtime is specific one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in the [Types of portability in .NET Core](https://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/app-types.html) article in the .Net Core documentation.

In short, by default, .Net Core applications are portable, which means that you can for example run `dotnet publish` on Windows and then run that application using `dotnet yourapp.dll` on any supported platform, including Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks! Great article. In my case of standalone application needed to specify `--runtime` parameter after `dotnet publish`